# How does layout (programmatically) work with data-binding without xml, in kotlin android development?

Tags: kotlin, layout, data-binding

I prefer to layout programmatically in kotlin, android app development. But as I know so far, data-binding has specific binding way working with xml layout, such as "< variable >...".
What if all my layout is not xml implemented and fully programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your query, you should use the java way to create views. Eg.

```
val textView = TextView(context)
```

Besides, if you are really eager to use it that way, I would suggest to go with [anko layouts](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts)

Comment: Anko is no longer updated though. Thanks for your idea.